# How to migrate userstories and tasks from rally to tfs?

Tags: tfs, rally

I Would like to know, how to migrate user stories and tasks from rally to TFS.
i have tried importing user stories and tasks from excel. But challenge is how to find relation between US/Task.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rally, but a generic answer to bulk creation of work items is to import via Excel. I'm not sure what your problem is, or what finding a relation between US/Task means. You should be able to copy and paste data to whatever fields you need, though you may have some difficulty with workflow (state) restrictions. I'm also not sure whether this is a one-time migration or a continual sync migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your flat list to a tree list by adding a tree level in Excel:

[image]

Then you'll see an additional Title 2 column has been inserted. Enter titles for UserStory items under Title 1 and for Tasks, under Title 2. Also, select the corresponding work item type for each. And publish your worksheet:

[image]